# Multi-dimensional array and objects with properties

Tags: javascript

I'm very new in Javascript and just started to learn objects and arrays. I got very confused trying to build a two-dimensional array of products. The first array consists of categories. Each category is an array of products. Each product is an instance of the product object. Like

```
for car: Honda, Toyota, Ford, etc.
a Honda can consist of :

Civic, 1997, VIN#123435678, 30000 miles, good condition, $12000, etc.
Accord, 1990, VIN#203948574, 100000 miles, good and running, $1000, etc.
So an instance of a car can be a Honda. And Honda can be an array of Accord, Civic, etc
```

What I create is:

```
var salsa1 = new Product("Salsa", "Victor Manuelle", "2013", "17.00");
      var salsa2 = new Product("Salsa", "Grupo Niche", "2012", "15.00");
      var salsa = new Array();
      salsa.push(salsa1);
      salsa.push(salsa2);

      var bachata1 = new Product("Bachata", "Romeo Santos", "2011", "15.00");
      var bachata2 = new Product("Bachata", "Joan Soriano", "2013", "18.50");
      var bachata = new Array();
      bachata.push(bachata1);
      bachata.push(bachata2);

      var products = new Array();
      var count = products.push(salsa);
      count = products.push(bachata);

      document.write("<table border='0'><tr><th>Type of Music</th><th>Artist Name</th><th>Year of release</th><th>Price for CD</th></tr>");
      for (var i=0; i<count; i++)
      {
        document.write("<tr>");
        document.write("<td>" + products[i][0].type + "</td>");
        for (var j=0; j<products[i].length; j++)
        {
            products[i][j].showProduct();
            document.write("</tr><td></td>");
        }

      };
```

But this way is not right. Please, give me some suggestions on how to get to the right way of solution!

Comment: It is more efficient (and easier for the HTML engine) if you build a single HTML string and write it in one go (i.e. a single `document.write` call), otherwise it must deal with invalid HTML along the way. A table **must** have a closing tag (they can be omitted for TRs and TDs). An opening TD tag can't immediately follow a closing TR tag, it must follow an opening TR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript object as associative array.

```
var products = {cars: [], musics: []};
products.cars.push({name: 'Something', year: 2005, ...});
products.musics.push({title: 'Something', artist: 'Someone', ...});
for (var key in products) {
    if (products.hasOwnProperty(key)) { //remove any inherited property
        var items = products[key];
        // do something
    }
}
```